Is there any ethical concern with a husband and wife serving as guest editors for a special issue?
My wife and I both have PhDs in the same field. I am currently in academia (post doc), she conducts research for a non profit (research scientist). I was asked to lead a special issue in a journal (journal is reputable in my field) in a research area I've dedicated my entire career to, so I'm happy to do so. The journal asked if I have colleagues I could recommend to serve as co guest editors.
In conversation with my wife, she expressed interest in this as she has overlapping expertise. I thought it was a reasonable idea, but then I thought that it might be perceived as unethical. I'm not sure if that is the consensus opinion. Perception is important  in my view. I strive to be an ethical academic. The fact I'm having to ask this question makes me think that there is an unethical perception. To summarize my question, is a husband and wife co-editor team on a journal special issue perceived as unethical?

I don't see an ethical issue around you suggesting your spouse, among others. It doesn't seem to raise any conflict of interest. It will be the journal that decides on whether they are the best choice.
One issue they might raise, though it isn't an ethical issue, is whether a more idea-diverse set of guest editors might lead to a better product. If you and your spouse "think alike" on what is important in the field as applied to a special issue, then having one of you is sufficient.
Your description, however, is that they are competent and involved enough in the field to do a good job. It would be different if you nominated your secondary school age child for a position for which they weren't qualified to give them a boost on their college admissions.
But, since you aren't the one making the decisions here, there is no ethical issue for you. Perceptions are up to the journal to manage.
If the spouse is the only one you recommend, then it gets more sensitive. But if you name a few others, including your spouse, I see no issues.
Note: I don't mean to imply that spouses necessarily "think alike", but that could be the perception. The same would be the case for two unrelated people who very frequently publish together.

Also, OP should tell the journal that they are married to the person

I think it is a conflict of interest that should be declared, but not an ethical issue.
